# Unable to view messages in HermesJMS + Solace

Tags: solace, hermes-jms

1. I created a successful SolaceSession on HermesJMS. Im able to successfully send message to the JMS queue (TEST.1) from HermesJMS (HermesJMS>>Messages>>Send a text message).

   > > I can see the Messages Spooled count increased by 1 in the SolAdmin.
2. But when i browse the JMS queue (TEST.1) from HermesJMS, Im not able to view them in HermesJMS.

   > > At the bottom, i see this message on HermesJMS:
   > >     Browsing TEST.1 on SolaceSession: Done
   > >     Also this message:
   > >     Finished. No messages read.
3. Upon checking the hermes.log, i see the following message:

2018-07-13 09:57:07,654 [Context_3_ReactorThread] DEBUG com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.flow.SubFlowManagerImpl - Demux pub msg:com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPGenericXMLMessage[**messageId=29609213**,ackMessageId=0,prevId=0,CID_count=0,userData=,type=PERSISTENT,priority=-1,redelivered=false,timeToLive=0,expiration=0,dmqEligible=false,topicSeqNum=null,metadataLen=0,contentLen=94,attLen=0,deliverToOne=false,ackImmediately=false,sendCount=0]

> > Message ID is the same as in SolAdmin.

2018-07-13 09:57:07,670 [Context_3_ReactorThread] DEBUG com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.flow.SubFlowManagerImpl - Received incoming message with no active flow found for flowId=8676, ignoring.

Could you please let me know why Solace is ignoring the message eventually hermesJMS wouldnt show it up.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi..Could you please hint on who will create the flow as mentioned in this log excerpt:
>>Received incoming message with no active flow found.

Im literally stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've not added the `-DSolace_JMS_Browser_Timeout_In_MS=1000` JVM system property to Hermes. You can refer to https://dev.solace.com/integration-guides/hermes-jms/ for full details about how to setup Hermes to work with Solace.

If the issue is not fixed even after setting `-DSolace_JMS_Browser_Timeout_In_MS=1000`, please provide the full set of logs.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Russell Sim. I did add the -DSolace_JMS_Browser_Timeout_In_MS=1000 in the hermes.bat file but to no avail. Please find the full log below:

Comment: Note that your link does not appear to be the full log. We are missing entries such as `DEBUG com.solacesystems.jms.SolConnection  - Creating connection.  Properties used for connection creation:` which is immediately followed by a complete list of all properties used. However, from what is given, the answer remains the same. `-DSolace_JMS_Browser_Timeout_In_MS` is not set.